# Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

i tried to use php pdo to connect to mysql so i uncomment

```
 extension=pdo_mysql
```

in the php.ini and any php action shows me this warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
```

i check where is the file that cannot open(/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql) and it did exist and is full o characters.I haven't try to make use of pdo in the code but i'm guessing that is not going to work and i haven't found any helpful solution. thanks before anything

PD. i'm using ubuntu 18.06

Comment: See this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04